# (mod_rewrite) Redirect / cloack to subdirectory

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to redirect

http://www.domain.com

to

http://www.domain.com/subdir/

with "/subdir" being cloaked from the user. At least in his url-bar.

What I figured out based on my rudimentary knowledge:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(/(.*))?$ http://www.domain.com/subdir/$1 [P,L]
```

It's working in terms of redirection, but it's not cloacking.
Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, according to the [official mod_rewrite documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html), if the substituion part is an absolute URL then an external redirect might happen (causing the URL to change in the user's browser; however, mod_rewrite should check if that absolute URL matches the request and strip that part out, but I've checked it for version 2.2 and the redirect happens).

So, one idea would be to use a relative URL like `/subdir/$1`

This looks good, but it does not solve your problem, because it does not work at all.

Instead, I suggest something like this to *always internally* add `subdir/`:

```
RewriteRule ^subdir/.* - [PT]
RewriteRule (.*) /subdir/$1
```

A short explanation:

- The first slash `/` is not included in the pattern, resulting in this pattern:

  - `http://www.domain.com/` --> `''`
  - `http://www.domain.com/dir1/file1.html`--> `dir1/file1.html`
- To prevent adding `subdir/` repeatingly/recursively the first rule Passes Through [PT] if it's yet modified
- The second rule then adds the `subdir/` before what was entered

Note that this two rules *always* add `subdir/` in the URL internally (not visible to the user). If you just want to add that part for requests to the root directory, then you need to modify the rules, of course - to get help on that you might clarify the use-case in your question.

If you plan to use mod_rewrite more often I highly suggest reading the [mod_rewrite documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) for your Apache server version (I guess 2.0 or 2.2 in your case) and maybe some blog articles (or even other questions here at SO).

Comment: Thanks for the solution, tips, explanation and even a reading suggestion :-) And yes, it works now!

Answer (score 0):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule (?!^subdir/)^(.*)$ /subdir/$1 [L,NC]
```